# Entity Framework Fetch Parent of Parent

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following data model:

```
Agenda->AgendaSection->SectionItem
```

Starting with the Item, I need to fetch both the Section and Agenda.

I've tried the following (and other things):

```
IList<AgendaSectionItem> myTasks = 
    db.AgendaSectionItems.Where(i => i.AssigneeId == currentUser.UserId)
                         .Include(i => i.AgendaSection)
                         .Include(s => s.AgendaSection.Agenda)
                         .ToList();
```

However, the Agenda ends up being null.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,

Philip

Comment: Have you tried removing that first Include call (`.Include(i => i.AgendaSection)`)`?

Comment: *However, the Agenda ends up being null* It shouldn't be if the model/mapping is correct. Are you using Code First? If yes, can we see the model and configuration if any. Or at least the generated SQL (hope this is not EF Core).

Comment: @IvanStoev How do I get the generated SQL?

Comment: @DevNoob That worked, please upgrade to an answer and I will accept.  I don't know why it works but it does.

Comment: IvanStoev: To see the query: breakpoint in debugger. examine your IQueryable. It has a non-public property` _internalQuery`. That property contains the Select statement

Comment: @PhilipTenn I'm not sure why either, but I have had this problem before where it only respects the first call to `Include`.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the first include statement.  I have had issues in the past with multiple include calls for whatever reason.  It should work with just the one call:

```
IList<AgendaSectionItem> myTasks = 
db.AgendaSectionItems.Where(i => i.AssigneeId == currentUser.UserId)
                     .Include(s => s.AgendaSection.Agenda)
                     .ToList();
```